# solr 6.3.0 not starting Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I am trying to run solr on my machine. I have made everthing available for the same.

For example java and ruby versions are same as asked in the tutorials around.

This is how I am doing it.

```
solr_wrapper -d solr/config/ --collection_name hydra-development --version 6.3.0
```

This throws the followign error.

> `exec': Failed to execute solr start:  (RuntimeError)
>   Port 8983 is already being used by another process (pid: 1814)
>   Please choose a different port using the -p option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message clearly indicates that some other process is using port 8983.
U need to find which process and try killing it
first run

```
$ lsof -i :8983
```

This will list applications running on port 8983. Lets say the pid of the process is 1814
run

```
$ sudo kill 1814
```

if you run into `Error CREATEing SolrCore`, it is mostly because of the permission issues caused by root installation

first cleanup the broken core:

```
bin/solr delete -c mycore
```

and recreate core as the solr user

```
su -u solr -c "/opt/solr/bin/solr create_core -c mycore"
```

Comment: `lsof -i :8983`

this returned nothing for me

Comment: o.k run the solr again, See the error message displaying pid, and kill the process

Comment: Damn, ran again no issue with pid but different error. :(

`ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'hydra-development': Unable to create core [hydra-development] Caused by: Lock held by this virtual machine:`

Comment: I get command not found error when I run this under my solr directory